# Python : read text file character by character in loop

Tags: python, python-3.x

For example, there's a text file which contains numbers from 0 to 9:

> 0123456789

Using the following function, I'd like to get output like this:

```
>>> print_char('filename')
0
>>> print_char('filename')
1
>>> print_char('filename')
2
.
.
.
>>> print_char('filename')
9
```

That means, every time I call the function it returns the next number.

Here's my function:

```
def print_char(filename):
    f = open(filename, 'r')
    while True:
        char=f.read(1)
        if not char: 
            break
        print(char)
```

...and the output I've got:

```
>>> print_char('filename')
0
1
2
3
.
.
.
9
```

So, how to create the function which will return character by character on every call?

Comment: You need to somehow share state (number of characters that have been read, or just opened file) between `print_char` function calls. You can use global variables for that, though this approach is considered a bad design. Do you really need `print_char` free function with such behavior?

Comment: Your proposed API is not good. `x = Reader('filename'); x.next(); x.next() ...` would be better.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart `next(x)`.

Comment: I realized I was for some reason assuming your file was newline separated, so my solution does not help you since you do not have a newline separated file. The new solution posted by Antti should give you what you want.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'd approach this differently, and make a function that takes in a filename that returns a generator:

```
def reader(filename):
    with open(filename) as f:
        while True:
            # read next character
            char = f.read(1)
            # if not EOF, then at least 1 character was read, and 
            # this is not empty
            if char:
                yield char
            else:
                return
```

Then you need to give the filename only once

```
r = reader('filename')
```

And the file is kept opened for much faster operation. To fetch next character, use the `next` built-in function

```
print(next(r))  # 0
print(next(r))  # 1
...
```

You can also use `itertools`, such as `islice` on this object slice characters, or use that in a `for` loop:

```
# skip characters until newline
for c in r:
    if r == '\n':
        break
```

Comment: This assumes that there are no NUL bytes in the file, and would terminate early if there were. I would change the `if char` test (which would fail on NUL) to a more explicit `if len (char) == 1`.