# can anyone explain me difference between these two codes

Tags: python, file, file-handling, difference

i have a file containing

```
First Second
```

can someone tell the difference between this approch

```
>>> for aa in open('test.txt'):
>>>    print(aa)
'First Second\n'
```

and this

```
>>> for aa in open('test.txt').read():
>>>    print(aa)
F
i
r
s
t

S
e
c
o
n
d

/
```

thanks

Comment: Can you please format this more clearly? I have a hard time understanding what is code and what is your annotation.

Comment: string="abcd"
lis=[]
a=string[0]+string[1]
lis=a
#for item in string:
    #lis.append(item)    output  ==== ab                but when i use      string="abcd"
   lis=[] 
for item in string:
    lis=list+item    it gives error  that "can only concatenate list (not "str") to list" howz that possible we can add  string[0] and string [1] to list but cannot add  item to list

Answer (score 0):

your firs approach read the file line by line

```
>>> for aa in open('test.txt'):
>>>    print(aa)
'First Second\n'
```

the second approach read the file char by char.

```
>>> for aa in open('test.txt').read():
>>>    print(aa)
F
i
r
s
t

S
e
c
o
n
d
```

related to: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27577788/8069500) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40330027/python-read-text-file-character-by-character-in-loop)

Comment: i didnt understand ,when we use read() to read the contents of file ,the output  is always in the form of lines eg.   s=open("test.txt").read()     print(s)    output-> First Line
Second Line            but when i did in loop it print in char by char .   D.s i m new to python

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#methods-of-file-objects